# 'Converting' or switching from Ashkenaz to Sepharadic traditions

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi

My immediate family is Asheknaz.
Can I 'switch' traditions / halacha to Sepharadi entirely? Obviously that brings both leniencies as well as more restrictions in other areas.

Comment: We are not a rabbi, but you should go find one to speak to.

Comment: Hey Winter, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Can you [edit] your question to make it less personal? We [try to avoid practical halachic questions](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. We hope to see you around!

Comment: Gotcha. I made it more general. If you think it's ready please reopen it :)