# Is one allowed to become a Talmid HaRambam?

Tags: halacha, minhag, rambam, mesorah-tradition, rebbe-talmid-muvhak

There is a movement of people (including several MiYodeya users I've seen) who believe in following the teachings of the Rambam exclusively, basing their practical halachot off the Mishneh Torah, despite not having been raised to do so.  These people tend to call themselves Talmidei HaRambam.

Do any poskim hold that it is permissible for one not raised in a Teimenite minhag to switch to following his rulings (and by implication ignore contradicting rulings from later poskim)?  If not, how are such people treated in halacha?

Comment: IINM R Ovadia Yosef permitted an Ashkenazi to become a Sefardi (through hatarat nedarim etc.). I don't see why this should be different.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33946&st=&pgnum=6

Comment: I seem to recall seeing a duplicate of this question, but in the meanwhile, here is a related (non-duplicate) question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26744

Comment: @DoubleAA This is speculation, but I would think it would be different as switching from Ashkenaz to Sefardi is a "horizontal" switch between two parallel and current traditions, whereas Talmidei Harambam are almost "regressing" to a historic ruling of a Rishon and disregarding all other subsequent stuff (notably the Beit Yosef) that has become minhag yisrael and accepted halacha.

Comment: @eliyahu-g Switching to Temanese those should be ok, and there are some of them IIUC who by and large did not accept the Bet Yosef's rulings. Maybe it's not 100% but it's closer

Comment: Somewhat similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/49147

Comment: @eliyahu-g You're mischaracterizing Rambamists. Understanding that various minhagim are counter intuitive for living and belief/philosophy =/= just asking MT for every answer. If we were regressing in a halachic sense then we wouldn't use modern inventions because Rambam never paskened on them.

Comment: I mean, you're supposed to adopt the minhagim of which ever community you move into. So obviously if you move into some Temoni neighborhood, then you aren't going to be keeping kitniyot most likely.

Comment: @DoubleAA "_IINM R Ovadia Yosef permitted an Ashkenazi to become a Sefardi_". If I recall correctly: (a) That is in Israel, where he said that the _Beit Yosef_ is the _Mara de-Atra_. (b) For the same reason, he insisted Yemenite and North African Jews, who moved to Israel, follow the _Beit Yosef_. (c) He opposed Sephardic students, who were studying in Ashkenazi Yeshivahs, adopting _Minhag Ashkenaz_.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the responsa collection of the Beth Yosef, [Avqath Rokhel #32](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=636&st=&pgnum=70) he defends those who conduct themselves according to the Rambam, even in a place where the majority of people follow another *poseq* (in this case, the Rosh). The turn of phrase that indicates that one can do so regardless of their familial tradition is: "...especially if they have a tradition from their fathers..." In other words, a person should not be forbidden from following the Rambam ESPECIALLY if they have a family tradition of doing so, which implies that one should not be forbidden from doing so even if they don't.

However, there are other very important considerations to such an undertaking:

1. ***To be a "Talmidh HaRambam" one must follow ALL of his leniencies and ALL of his stringencies***: This is even stated by the Beth Yosef here in this *teshuvah*. This means only eating eating certain *shekhittoth* of meat (which cannot be found easily in Israel, and not at all outside of Israel), your wife wearing a *hi-jab* to cover her hair and neck, your young girls covering their hair as well, and this is only to name a few. The Jewish reality codified by the Rambam is a completely different reality in many respects to the one occupied by religious Jewry today. One cannot become a *"Talmidh HaRambam"* in order to eject from many of the stringencies of mainstream orthodoxy today and not follow the Rambam when he is strict or a *da`ath yahidh*.
2. ***There never in history existed "Talmidhei HaRambam" as such***: Throughout Jewish history since the publication of the Mishneh Torah there has never been a concept of only and always following the Rambam. Not in Yemen, not in Aleppo, not in Eress Yisra'el, nowhere. There were always minor exceptions in both matters of *minhagh* and *halakhah* as there most likely was even among those whom the Beth Yosef defends in his *teshuvah*. Even the Rambam himself and his son, Rabbenu Avraham, did not follow the rulings codified in the Mishneh Torah 100%. There are various reasons for this, not the least of which are situations of halakhic need which require certain innovations or the invocation of other opinions. To be a "Talmidh HaRambam" in the sense of following the Rambam in absolutely every opinion he holds - to the exclusion of all else - is a relatively new phenomenon that is not at all possible and has caused many problems among those who have tried.
3. ***One needs a competent Rav in the tradition of the Rambam***: The best way, *le-`aniyuth da'ati* to follow the Rambam in our time - and in any time - is to connect oneself with a Rav in the tradition of the Rambam. This would mean either a Yemenite, a Syrian, or many of the Sefardic *rabbanim* in the world today. Or, one could also find a *meqori* Rav to learn from who is largely based on the Rambam (but not exclusively so), such as Rav Dawidh Bar Hayyim of Yerushalayim. The fact is that Rav Qaro in the Shulhan Arukh rules like the Rambam through direct quotations approximately 85% of the time, so Sefaradim who are true to the Gemara over the Qabbalah are fairly close to the Rambam most of the time. Not only will this help to avert the plethora of errors made by those who try to forge their own path in the Rambam (often without even being able to read and understand Hebrew), but it will also help a person be consistent and able to navigate all of the non-ideal halakhic situations that arise in the course of normal everyday life.

As far as how such people are treated in *halakhah*, they are treated like every other religious Jew. However, in today's *haredi* world, anyone who does anything different than the status quo is often branded an "apikoros" for daring defy the words of the [Ashkenazi] "gedolim." If Sefaradim are often treated like second-class citizens, I can tell you that Yemenites are treated even worse than that many times for the "crime" of following the Mishneh Torah over the Shulhan Arukh. Many reading this may not like such a statement, but I maintain that my assessment is true and accurate. So, I am not saying that one should not pursue such a path, but only that one should know what they are getting into before they do so.

Hope that this helps.

Kol tuv.

Comment: He mentions that the answer was to a kehilla. A Kehilla could be different than a Yachid.

Comment: @Shmuel Brin - Read the linked teshuvah. It is abundantly clear that the reasoning of the Beth Yosef concerning a qehilah flows from that which he views as true of an individual. Kol tuv.

Comment: (1) The responsa in _Shu"T Avqat Rokhel_ were written over 400 years ago. Which _Poseqim_ today allow people to become _Talmidei ha-Rambam_? (2) "... _which implies that one should not be forbidden from doing so even if they don't_" Does that mean one can change from a Sephardic _Minhag_ to an Ashkenazic one (or vise-versa), regardless of the _Mara de-Atra_ where he lives?

Comment: @Maimonist what's the source for the Rambam not following all the Halachos in the Mishna Torah?

Comment: @Bochur613 - It is evident from several of his teshuvoth that in less than ideal situations, the Rambam chooses other views or circumvents what is codified in the MT. He also differs in several ways from the MT in the Moreh Nevukhim. Try looking at the Rambam's position on using a pasul sefer Torah in a Ssibbur. Hope this helps. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist look at mori qafi7's mt:  See הלכות תפלין ומזוזה וספר תורה פ"י הל' א אות א where he wrote "וזו היא דעתו האחרונה להבחין בין חומש העשוי כתקנו, לספר שאינו עשוי כתקנו, ובצעירותו לא הבחין כזאת, אלא היו בעיניו שוין לפי שנמשך אחרי חכמי נרבונא וכמ"ש בתשובה"

Comment: that tashuvo is before the mt, and he changes his mind in the mt

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob - I fully respect Mori Yusuf z"l and his understanding of the issue. However, there really is no evidence that he "changed his mind" other than a linear understanding of his writings. So, did the Rambam "change his mind" when he wrote in Hilkhoth Shabbath - in accordance with the law brought in the Gemara - that it is permitted to carry/wear amulets that are considered efficacious on Shabbath while denying that such things are effective in the Moreh? Or is it that he faithfully codifies the rulings of Hazal even if his own opinion differs? ...

Comment: ... The ideal law is what is written in the MT, but it doesn't (and cannot possibly) account for all of the non-ideal circumstances of life. And no one, not even the Rambam, is 100% consistent in everything they say or believe about halakhah since the varied and imperfect circumstances of life disallow it. And, this isn't the only example, there are others. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist the rashbo zl offers the same explanation, stating that it was written in his younger age. i will write up a pieceo n the saghulloth soon ba3azrath hasheim.