# Praise of Mishneh Torah amongst the Rishonim

Tags: halacha, rambam, rishonim, mishneh-torah

The Mishneh Torah is often described as one of the cornerstones of Jewish literature. The Rambam, in his introduction to this magnum opus, describes his book as being written:

> כֻּלָּן בְּלָשׁוֹן בְּרוּרָה וְדֶרֶךְ קְצָרָה, עַד שֶׁתְּהֶא תּוֹרָה שֶׁבְּעַל פֶּה כֻּלָּהּ סְדוּרָה בְּפִי הַכֹּל.‏
>
> All written in a lucid language and with brevity, so that all people will be well versed in the totality of the Oral Law.

Do we find praise of the Mishneh Torah among Rishonim (medieval scholars, generally 11th-16th century) that echo these sentiments: namely, its inclusivity of the entirety of the Oral Law, its profound brevity and precision of language, or further praise? Obviously, its acceptance into the canon of Jewish law is praise in of itself, but I am looking for articulated praise.

This is relevant to Judaism because the Mishneh Torah is regarded as a central text of Jewish law, and the opinions of other Rishonim about it would seemingly carry weight in terms of its importance and application. It could also give us a new sense of appreciation of the depth and profundity of this work, assuming such praise exists. (I am specifically looking for positive comments from Rishonim, not negative.)

Example: R. Shmuel Kalai (16th century) in his Shu"t Mishpatei Shmuel #120, writes:

> כל דברי רבינו הם בתכלית הדיוק ויש לדקדק ולפלפל בדבריו כאשר תוכל לדקדק בגמרא עצמה. וכ"כ המגדל עוז בתשובותיו להשגות בדוכתי טובא.‏

Comment: does this include communities that went by the rambam+communities that petitioned to adhere to the mt but were rejected by the presiding authority over the community at the time in rishonic times

Comment: Try Samuel ben Judah ibn Tibbon, who translated a lot of Rambam's writings and was in contact with him during that time. He was from France I believe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The Meiri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Meiri) (13th cent.) describes the unique features of the Mishneh Torah in his introduction to Beit HaBehira:

1. That it is omits the Talmudic dialectics, and presents just ruling.
2. That it is written in Mishnaic Hebrew.
3. That it includes all laws; even those which are not practically applicable.
4. That it includes material from a great number of sources including the Yerushalmi, Tosefta, and Geonic rulings.

He concludes that the work is complete and comprehensive, upon it one cannot add, and from it one cannot detract. There was no comparable work before it, nor will such a work ever be authored again!

> והרב מורה צדק חדש בחבורו תכונות אחרות וזה שהוא ע"ה אחז דרך המחברים לכתוב כל דבר ודבר ביחד הלכות הלכות אבל **חדש עליהם לכתוב דבריו דרך קבלה באין הודעת מחלוקת** ומשא ומתן וכן **חדש עליהם לכתוב דבריו בלשון המשנה** והוסיף אומץ **לכתוב בחבוריו כל עניני התלמוד הן בענינים הצריכים לנו בזה הזמן הן בשאר הענינים** ועל זה הצד כלל בספריו דרך קצרה כל התלמוד עם כל **מה שראה בעין שכלו להוסיף בו מן הירושלמי ומן התוספתא ומשאר המקומות הזרים עם מה שנתחדש בדברי הגאונים** מאין הודעת מחלוקת ומשא ומתן ומאין הודעת הדברים ההם איזהו מקומן **עד שיודע הכל הלכות הלכות בשלמות חבור כולל ושלם עליו אין להוסיף וממנו אין לגרוע לפניו לא היה כן מחבורי הגאונים והרבנים חבור מסדר כל הענינים בחכמת התלמוד איש על דגלו בסדור מתוקן ושלם כמוהו ואחריו לא יהיה כן**

The brevity, style, greatness, and ubiquity of the Mishneh Torah, were similarly noted by [R. Menahem ibn Zerah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menahem_ben_Aaron_ibn_Zerah) (14th cent.) who writes in the [introduction of Tsedah Laderekh](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39362&st=&pgnum=18):

> ומי שחקר...ידע אשר ערך ותקן הלכותיו ופרקיו...ובמה שכלל בשטה אתח מפרקיו ידע כמה היה גדול ומי יוכל לבא עד תכונתו ומי ישיג צחות לשונו בעברי קצר הבנין ורחב הענין והתפשטו ספריו בכל נפוצות הגולה
>
> One who investigates...will know that he ordered and arranged his laws and chapters...and from that which he included in a single line of a single chapter, one can realise how great he was, and who can grasp his nature, and who can fathom his expertise with the Hebrew language; short in words, but vast in substance, and his works have spread to all those scattered throughout the diaspora.

Even Rambam's famous disputant, [Rabbi Avraham ben David](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ben_David) (12th cent.) writes (in his critiques to Hilkhot Kilayim 6:2), that Rambam performed a notable feat by gathering material from the Bavli, Yerushalmi, and Tosefta:

> מלאכה גדולה עשה באסיפתו דברי הגמרא והירושלמי והתוספתא
>
> He performed a great feat in assembling the words of the Gemara, and the Yerushalmi, and the Tosefta.

The comprehensiveness of the Mishneh Torah was similarly noted implicitly by [Rivash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_ben_Sheshet) (14th cent.) in a responsum (#45), who noted that although Rambam studied and wrote about philosophy, he also mastered the entire corpus of rabbinic literature as is evident from the Mishneh Torah:

> כי הוא למד...כל התורה כולה בשלמות, הלכות ואגדות, תוספת', ספרא וספרי וכולי' תלמודא, בבלי וירושלמי, כמו שנראה מספר משנה תורה שחבר
>
> For he studied the entire Torah completely, halakhot and aggadot, Tosefta, Sifra, Sifrei, and the entire Talmud; Bavli and Yerushalmi, as is evident from the Mishneh Torah.

The uniqueness of the Mishneh Torah, particularly its comprehensiveness, was also noted by [R. Moses of Coucy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_ben_Jacob_of_Coucy) (13th cent.) in he introduction to his Sefer Mitsvot Gadol:

> ועמד האיש הגדול רבינו משה ב"ר מיימון היה מקורדו"בה...ועשה חיבור מכל התורה חיבור נאה ומשובח והאיר עיני ישראל...לא נשמע בדורות אחרונות כמוהו
>
> And the great man, Rabenu Moshe son of Rabbi Maimun from Cordoba arose...and composed a compilation of the entire Torah; a nice and praiseworthy compilation, and he illuminated the eyes of Israel...In the later generations, the likes of him have not been found.

The authority and ubiquity of the Mishneh Torah was noted by [R. Yitshak HaYisraeli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Israeli_ben_Joseph) (13th-14th cent.) who wrote in Yesod Olam ([IV:18](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32674&st=%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%95&pgnum=76)):

> נשתדל לחבר חיבורו הגדול והנפלא שנקרא אותו משנה תורה...ונתפשטו בכל גלויות ישראל הסכימו כל ישראל לנהוג בהם ולעשות על פיהם בכל דיני התורה והתקנות והגזרות והמנהגות
>
> He laboured to compose his great and wondrous compilation which he called Mishneh Torah...and [his works] spread among all the exiles of Israel, and all of Israel agreed to conduct themselves according to them and to act according to them in all laws of the Torah, and the enactments, restrictions, and customs.

---

Additionally, numerous communities in the period of the Risohnim followed the Mishneh Torah exclusively (or almost exclusively), as endorsed by their rabbis.

For example, R. Tsemah (son of [Rashbash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_ben_Simon_Duran)) writes in Shu"t Yakhin UBoaz (II:23) that in some places such as his locale אלגזאי"ר (Algeria?), whose custom is to follow the Mishneh Torah exclusively (except for three exceptions). This was the consensus of the rabbis there [Rivash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_ben_Sheshet) (14th cent.) and [Rashbats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simeon_ben_Zemah_Duran) (14th-15th century). Other than those three exceptions, they state that residents of those areas mustn't veer at all from the Mishenh Torah, whether leniently, or stringently:

> ויש מקומות מתנהגים עפ"י הרמב"ם ז"ל ואינם נוטים מדעתו כמו מקומנו זה אלגזאי"ר שהרבנים הראשונים שהיו בכאן מורינו הרי"בש ז"ל ומורינו הרשב"ץ ז"ל הסכימו שיתנהגו על משנה תורה זולתי בג' מקומות...ובזולתם אין לזוז ולא נטה ימין ושמאל מדעתו בין זכות בין חובה בין להקל בין להחמיר

Similarly, writing in early 16th century Egypt, [Radvaz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_ben_Solomon_ibn_Abi_Zimra) writes in a responsum (II:424) that Rambam is considered the local authority and that his rulings have been accepted in "all these regions":

> הרמב"ם מאריה דאתרא הוא וכבר קבלו כל אלו הגלילות פסקי דינו

Similarly, [R. Yosef Karo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Karo) wrote a responsum (Avkat Rokhel 32) regarding the question of whether communities who follow Rambam should be forced to follow [Ri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_ben_Samuel) and later authorities. R. Karo responds forcefully that they should not stop following Rambam, and that all the communities in the land of Israel, Arabistan (I assume [Khuzestan Province](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khuzestan_Province)), and the [Maghreb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maghreb) have accepted Rambam as their rabbi, and follow his rulings.

> הרמב"ם ז"ל אשר הוא גדול הפוסקי' וכל קהלות ארץ ישראל והאראביסטאן והמערב נוהגים על פיו וקבלוהו עליהם לרבן

Comment: The Raabad is not exactly praising the Rambam, he is merely saying that it is a great and tedious work to gather all this information. Furthermore, the Raabad is looking to criticize the Rambam in every place and his objective was surely not to praise him, for that would defeat the purpose of his Hasagot. It is highly unlikely that he had this in mind. So i think we remain only with praise from the Meiri.

Comment: @Bach Praise is praise. A concession to the comprehensiveness of the MT in no way contradicts his critiques.

Comment: @Bach "Furthermore, the Raabad is looking to criticize the Rambam in every place" That is patently false. You clearly have not gone through all of the hassagot (or read quality secondary literature about them)

Comment: @mevaqesh excellent sources. Where can one find the Meiri's introduction to Beit HaBechira online?

Comment: @Chaim I can't find that Meiri online at the moment, but I did find the Meiri in [his introduction to Avot](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2835&st=%d7%94%d7%95%d7%93%d7%90%d7%aa+%d7%94%d7%93%d7%91%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%9d&pgnum=67) who describes ספר הרב הגדול נר מערבי עדות לכל העולם הרב רבינו משה ז"ל הודיע פסקי כל התלמוד דרך קצרה ודרך קבלה בסידור נאה מאד עם קצת סמך מהירושמי והתוספתא כמו שנודע ונתפרסם

Answer (score 2):

Ramba*n*, in his [letter](http://hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_43026_271.pdf) to the French sages who wanted to ban the Rambam's Sefer Ha-Madda and Moreh Nevuchim, writes at length in praise of the Rambam:

> והנה שם הרב ספריו כתריס בפני פורעניות, מגן הוא לחצי קשתי בני יון
>   החוקקים חקקי און, להעלות הטובעים בבור שאון מטיט היון...הוצאתם עתק מפיכם,
>   דברים הנראים לקנאה ושנאה נאמרין, אסור לשומעם אף כי לכותבם ומכש"כ
>   לאומרם, שכתבתם ואמרתם על הקדוש ההוא, בכל גלות צרפת וספרד לא קם כמוהו
>   המורה יורה, מי כמוהו מורה, ובכל מיני חכמות בקי, משנתו קב ונקי, פערתם פה
>   לבלי חק והעתרתם בדברים הנשמעים למרחוק, באמרכם על הגאון יש לנו גדול
>   ממנו שנעשה צדוקי, הנה זאת לא צדקתם אענכם, לא דברתם נכונה בעבד ה'
>   ואוכיחם...הלא שאלתם עוברי דרך, המאריכים לשון המפליגים מליצה, הנושאים
>   משל בערך, בתהלת הרב הגדול במעלת חסידותו בתוקף אמונתו בעוצם ענותנותו
>   בגדולת יחוסו בנדבת כיסו במעשיו הנפלאים במליו הנוראים, ביהותו ביראת אלקיו
>   דבק וחושק, ובתלמודנו נושק, אוהב דברי חכמים ומחבקן, הם מחמד עיניו ומחמד
>   לנפשו, עטרת לראשו. **האם ראיתם ספריו אם דקדקתם בחבוריו, השמעתם אותו מבעט
>   באיסורין בקלין וחמורין, אם השמיט כל תקנה וגזרה ועשה סיג לתורה, אם
>   העלים עיניו מעירובין וידים**, אם שכח עומר בגורן בעוף וגבינה הנאכלין
>   באפיקורן, והלא החמיר בהן ויותר מן הדין, לא לכם רבותינו להקל ראש כנגד
>   המזרח...הלא הרב ז"ל כי ה' עמו

In the continuation of the letter, Ramban expresses astonishment at the attempt to ban Sefer Ha-Madda:

> ואם יעלה על לבם מקצתן מגזרתכם וע"כ ספר המורה ירחיקו, ומדבר בעניניו
>   שפתותם ידביקו, כי לבם כמחט סדקית לא ידעו דרכיו ובנתיבותו לא העמיקו, מה
>   יאמרו לספר המדע והמכתב מכתב אלקים אשר העתיקו, מפתח לספרי הרב ז"ל
>   בתלמוד ומבוא לכל חבוריו, סופר מצות ה' עשה ולא תעשה, מלמד לתלמידים כבוד
>   ומורא בהלכות תלמוד תורה, יורה חטאים דרך בהלכות תשובה, ובנחת ושובה בלי
>   קושיא והויות, מפיק מרגליות, כי לא מצינו דברי תשובה בתלמוד רק מפוזרים
>   ומפורדים, בין ההלכות וההגדות בלי ברורים, ובכל חבורי גאונים הראשונים
>   ואחרונים לא מצינו אותם ענינים דרושים לכל חפציהם ומזומנים כאשר המה
>   מפורשים ומבואר בספר ההוא הממולא פנינים, המיוחס בספרים מבחוץ ומבפנים, ומחסדכם רבותינו הודיעונו מה לכם ולספר ההוא, כי תורה הוא וללמוד אנו צריכים

Comment: Bolded the part which includes his works in general (and implicitly the MT), as the question was about the MT; not the person.

Comment: "אם שכח עומר בגורן בעוף וגבינה הנאכלין באפיקורן והלא החמיר בהן ויותר מן הדין" A fascinating example to choose!

Comment: Do you know where I can get the entire letter in plain text online? Or did you type up those excerpts from the PDF?

Comment: @Chaim typed from PDF. It is also printed in Chavel's Kitvei Ramban

Comment: @wfb I have it in Chavel's. Feel free to type it all up!

Comment: do any of you have https://www.amazon.com/Ramban-Nachmanides-Writings-Discourses-Volumes/dp/0883280132 ????

Answer (score 2):

R. Levi ibn Habib (c. 1480 – c. 1545), also known by the acronym HaRaLBaCh, writes in his [responsum #12](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/ralbach/ralbach03.pdf):

> אין זה לומר שיקשה עלינו בדברי הרב לא להפילה ולא אפילו למעטם ממקומ' בהיות כונת הרב מפורשת בדבריו ואף כי יקשה לנו על דבריו מתוך שיטת התלמוד המפורסם אצלנו **ראוי והגון לנו לתלות החסרון במיעוט הקפתנו והשגתנו וחייבי' אנו לקבל דבריו מבלי שנהרהר אחריו כי לבו כלב האריה בהקפת התלמוד בבלי וירוש' תוספתא ספרי וספרא ואגדתא ואיזו סוגי' היתה סדור' לפניו** ואנו בעונותינו נסתרה מעינינו למיעוט הספרים ולקוצר השגתנו ואלו הי' הרב לפנינו היה פותח לנו פתח רחב יותר מפתחו של אולם וזו היא קבלה הגונה ואמיתית מפורש' אצלני מפי סופרי' ומפי ספרי'

My rough translation:

*This isn't to say that we should have a question on the words of the Rav (Rambam), nor to remove them or even minimize them from their place inasmuch as the Rav's intention is clear in his words. **Even when we have difficulty from his words based on the clear position of the Talmud, it is proper and fitting for us to place the burden of error upon our own lack of broad knowledge and clarity. And we are obligated to accept his words without casting doubt upon them, for his heart is like the heart of a lion in its' broad grasp of the Talmud Bavli and Yerushalmi, Tosefta, Sifri, Sifra and Agadita, and whatever topic was organized and clear before him.** It is due to our sins that our eyes have been veiled due to our lack of books and shortness of understanding. If only the Rav would be before us, he would open an opening (of clarity) far wider than an auditorium. This is a fitting and truthful tradition which is well-known amongst us from authors and books.*

Similarly, the [MaHaRShaCh](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94_%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9F_(%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%A9"%D7%9A)) (1540-1602) writes along the same lines in his responsa, [2:197](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=1130#p=278&fitMode=fitheight&hlts=&ocr=) (I was unable to find the actual quote inside, but R. Yosef Kafih z"l quotes him as such in the introduction to his edition of Rambam's Mishneh Torah).