# Where may I read Sefer Mitzvot Gadol online in English?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, translation, english

Does anyone know where I can read an online English translation of **Sefer Mitzvot Gadol**?

Note: *I've checked Sefaria, but they don't have an English translation.*

Comment: Is there an offline English translation?

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?

Comment: https://socialhistory.org.uk/shs_exchange/turning-a-13c-jewish-manuscript-into-comics/ According to here, there's no English translation currently available.

Comment: And I doubt that there would be. The SMaG has been eclipsed by latter works, and now it is very much a scholarly work that anyone who can't translate the Hebrew would have little need of studying.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87853/13438

Comment: @Dov There is no reason to think the thing the OP is seeking exists