# Is one allowed to be Machmir against a psak?

Tags: halacha-theory, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

- The Halacha follows Rabbi Yehoshua that a Mamzer is only if one marries an Erva that is Chayav Kares.
- The Halacha follows the opinion  that the descendants of a non-Jew living with a Jewess are Kosher Jews and not Mamzerim.

Now, there are opinions arguing both points. Rabbi Akiva says that anyone who's a result of an intimacy which violates a simple negative commandment is also a Kares. There are a few opinions (in Yevamos) which hold that the descendant of a non-Jew with a Jewess are Mamzerim.

Now, someone offers a Shidduch to my friend. Would it be Halachically acceptable to advise him not to marry those people, despite the Gemara/Rishonim/Shulchan Aruch clearly permitting them, as perhaps Mashiach would come, a Sanhedrin would reconvene, and perhaps rule like Rabbi Akiva/The other opinions.

What about if there was a piece of Chelev about which there was a debate, and the Halacha got ruled that it's Kosher. Is it still acceptable to not eat it (and to tell others not to), as perhaps the sages Gemara made a mistake, and when Moshiach would come and a Sanhedrin would be restored we would all have to bring a Korban Chatas (note, I'm assuming most Jews didn't eat this particular cut of meat so there would be no Par Helem Davar Shel Tzibbur).

Comment: I found the Piskei Teshuva (10) in [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4371) where he says that to be Machmir on something the Amoraim were not is Apikorsus. Yet, Lechora, why can't we just say that I'm "hedging my bets" so to say, as a Sanhedrin could re-open any case any time and undo any previous legislation.

Comment: For the record, he actually he says it's "like" Apikorsus. הוי כמו אפיקורסות ויצא שכרו בהפסדו. (And he seems to bring dissenting opinions.)

Comment: part of your question has to do with hilchot lashon hara. it may be assur even if it's not the best thing to marry such a person

Comment: A man can reject any shidduch he wants _for any reason_, no? Now whether that rejection is taken seriously/well, that is a different subject.

Comment: U can always be machmir on a psak. One has to know himself.

Answer (score 7):

1. Rabbi Eliezer spent the latter years of his life in Cheirem because he refused to accept a "majority" opinion that disagreed with his own.
2. In case you think that is doesn't apply to be "strict on yourself only", there's an incident in Mishnah ([Brachot 1:3](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berakhot.1.3?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all)) about Rabbi Tarfon who endangered himself to "lie down" to say the night-time K'riyat Shema. His colleagues said to him: you deserved to have something happen to you, because that is the rejected opinion of Beis Shammai and the halacha follows Beis Hillel (who state that "When you lie down" refers to the time of the night-time Kriyas Shema and not the bodily position).

In your case the accepted halachic opinion is that the descendent of a male non-Jew and a female Jew is fully Jewish and not a Mamzer (although I think if a female, a Kohen may be prohibited from marrying them, but they have extra restrictions anyway).

There are acceptable times to be extra machmir. The halacha is that during Sukkot, certain foods can be eaten outside the Sukkah yet in the Mishna we read about certain Rabbis who were stricter and asked "take it to the Sukkah" when offered such food. Rabban Gamliel would even only drink water in the Sukkah. (This however is not an issue of status of the food but simply a preference on the way they carry themselves. Your issues were on the status of a person with regards to marrying and with regards a piece of fat as to whether it is Cheilev when the accepted opinion is that it is Shamein. Nobody will force you to eat it but you shouldn't say it's Cheilev).

Comment: it's permitted but in this case could still be considered a pegam

Comment: Rabbi Eliezer was lenient. Can one be strict?

Answer (score 3):

There is a question that is similar to yours:

If a drop of milk falls into a pot of meat and there is 60 times more meat than the drop then the food is mutar.The question is, is it assur to throw out the food since one is uncomfortable to eat something which milk fell into even though it is 100 percent mutar or one cant be machmir on wasting mutar food?
The Pri Toar holds that one may be machmir on himself and not eat the food. However, the Toras Ha'asham holds very strongly that since the Torah said it is permitted one should eat it and not throw it out. Similarly, the Darchai Tshuva brings the Bnei Yisachar and Shla'ah that also say that one should eat it and there is no midas chasidus not to eat it rather it is a mitzvah to eat it. With this he explains the Chazal "גדול הנהנה מיגיע כפו יותר מירא שמים" that a person that legitimately works to find a proper heter for something and eats it is greater then one who has yiras shamaim and does not eat it.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add to what has already been said.

*Hazal* actually tell us when it is praiseworthy to go beyond what is required. They do this with the phrase "*harei zeh meshubahh* (הרי זה משובח) - Behold, [to do] this [action beyond what is technically required] is praiseworthy."

Beyond instances where this is stated, as has been highlighted in the other answers, *Hazal* frowned upon such actions and - to add one more source - it states in the *Talmudh Yerushalmi*, *Masekheth Shabbath* 1:2 ([7a](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r2101.htm)) the following:

> *wa-thani hhizqiyyah kol mi shehu patur min ha-davar wa-`osehu niqra hedyot*.

**Translation**:

"*Hhizqiyyah* taught, 'Everyone who is halakhically exempt from something, but does it anyway ***is an idiot***.'"

And just by way of appeal to common sense, if everyone were "*mahhmir*" against *pisqei* *halakhah*, imagine how erratic the Jewish world would be. And ultimately, treating people who are **not** - *le-fi ha-din* - *mamzerim* as though they are, or those who are not - *le-fi ha-din* - eating *hhelev* as though they are can and will only lead to ***sinath hhinam*** (baseless hatred/rejection).

Indeed, such ideas already popular among certain *haredi* groups have done this very thing, for they treat good religious Jews who are not *`avaryanim* as though they are because of their "*humroth*."

Kol tuv.

Comment: Is it necessary to malign `certain haredi groups` with the accusation that `they treat good religious Jews who are not 'avaryanim as though they are because of their "humroth"`? Could it be that this `will only lead to sinath hhinam`?

Comment: @Fred - I maligned no one. I stated facts without needless *ad hominem*. The fact is that "certain haredi groups" [not all] act this way. And it is only haredim who hate because of "*hhumroth*" - never have we heard of Dati Leumi or MO groups acting this way. It is a sad fact, but still a fact. And I mentioned it to illustrate mt point. Kol tuv.

Comment: No such "groups" exist, to the best of my knowledge. There are (at most) scattered individuals with this mindset, and they do not constitute a "group." And these scattered individuals have diverse religious backgrounds and persuasions; one person might favor a stringency in הלכות שבת, another in הלכות צדקה, another in הלכות תפילה, another might be stringent in opposing people who study in *kollel*, another might be stringent on wearing תכלת, and yet another person might be stringent against praying at gravesites...

Comment: Although it is rare for someone to be so vehement as to hate someone else with a different practice, this problem does not exist exclusively in the broader Haredi community; it exists among just about every religious subgroup, and it is symptomatic of a human flaw that any sort of religious or non-religious person could have.

Comment: I disagree based on a great deal of personal experience. The idea that it is scattered individuals and not a systemic problem on the haredi world is just simply untrue. And while human problems do exist wherever humans are found. The sub-groups I mentioned do not have these issues in common with the haredi community. They just don't.

Comment: I also have a great deal of experience with people from all segments of the religious world, and I totally disagree with the notion that this is more of a problem in the Haredi community than in other communities (there are just as many people who castigate Haredim as vice-versa). Regardless, it is unnecessary to include this type of tangential vitriol in your answer (and other answers, such as the final paragraph [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/52827)). The fact you have included these sort of extraneous remarks makes your perspective seem biased and your accusations unreliable.

Comment: Except for the fact that I am not referring here to general "castigation" of others on the part of any group. I am referring to *sinath hhinam* being expressed by haredi groups due to the fact that the Jewish groups they are hating do not subscribe to their "*hhumroth*". That is all I said and there was no vitriol included. All it would take to prove my statement is to cite two groups (the *miut* of "groups") that act in this fashion. Then my statements would be simple fact and yours would be needlessly argumentative. Would you like me to?

Comment: 1. The "Toldos Aharon" Hasidic group in *Eress Yisra'el* - particularly the group that "protested" in Beit Shemesh who spit on properly dressed Jewish girls coming out of school because they wore denim.

Comment: 2. The "Eidah HaChareidis" who funded group 1 and who funds nonsense like this all over Israel.

Comment: 3. Those who follow the Brisker Rav of *Yerushalayim* who was quoted as saying that non-haredi Jews who went to pray in Meron were "*shkutzim*"...shall I go on? And please don't think that I mean to categorize every haredi individual or group - I'm not and my statement cannot be construed to mean that.

Comment: 1. Neither Toldos Aharon nor the Eida supported spitting on the girls in Beit Shemesh; the protesters there were a few wackos acting on their own volition and not representing any group. 2. I've never heard of this reported statement by the Brisker Rav, but it doesn't sound authentic to me (unless there is some missing context?). | I wasn't accusing you of castigating all Charedim; I was saying that there are as many non-Charedim who have blanket `sinath hhinam` against Charedim (including for non-observance of stringencies like not learning in kollel) as there are vice-versa.

Comment: Although of course you could find legitimate of examples of individuals exhibiting `sinath hhinam` in either direction (though I  question the examples you provided), the point is that the nebulous remarks about `certain haredi groups` are both irrelevant to the question in the OP and also unfair and one-sided.

Comment: You have a serious case of denial. There is no amount of evidence that will sway you. What I said here and in the answer at the link you provided are 100% true. "Certain haredi groups" do act this way, Sefaradim are mistreated by Ashkenazim, and Yemenites are discounted by many in the haredi world for their "maqel" positions. And, yes, my positions are one-sided because I'm not haredi (anymore). But also because I refuse to overlook the sins of those in that camp and I refuse to blame the victims of their elitism and bigotry. I'm not changing my answer. Good day.

Comment: You're not obligated to change your answer, as I'm not obligated to approve of elements of your answer with which I disagree. | Unfortunately, there are some individuals who discriminate against Sefaradim (though I've never met one personally over the decades), as there are individuals who denigrate Ashkenazim. I'm not sure what you mean by `Yemenites are discounted by many in the haredi world for their "maqel" positions` ("discounted" in what sense?). I'm glad you admit your positions are one-sided, though I'm sad that you sweepingly indict "certain groups" of people as elitist and bigoted.

Comment: But are you obligated to badger me in the comments section of my answer? What are you seeking to do here? Change my mind? And how? If I am so one-sided and unfair, then why don't you bring evidence to counter my assertions? You have provided nothing but vague comments about how we're all human. This conversation is beyond pointless and should already have been moved to chat. But I don't do chat, so we're done. Good day, sir.

Comment: "Use comments... to suggest improvements." That doesn't mean you have to accept my suggestion. And if we were to veer off the tracks and get into the nitty gritty of who hates who and how much, this would be an endless dialogue. My objection to your indictment of swaths of Charedi or Ashkenazi society should suffice to convey the point that not everyone accepts that view.

Comment: I just want to add that I'm sorry if I have offended you. Perhaps some of my wording above was too harsh. In any case, I appreciate and enjoy many of your contributions on the site.

Comment: Thank you. Apology accepted. I got into it too. My bad. Your contributions are quality too. No worries, we Maimonists are slightly paranoid anyhow ;-) Kol tuv.